# HttpUrlConnection taking 100% CPU when running on CentOS

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, jmeter, cpu-usage

I have an HttPURLConnection program which is making a connection with some application which is running on the same machine(CentOS in this case) but deployed on some other tomcat server. This means an HttpConnection is made between the two applications deployed on different tomcats, where both tomcats are running on the same machine.

All works fine and i got the response within 200 milis when i make a single request.
But when the application is being loaded with 100 requests running in parallel for infinite loop via JMeter, the appication start taking the high CPU processing.

Here is my code:

```
public String sendHttpGetReq(String urlParameters,String msisdn, InNodeConfig inNodeConfig, InNodeDetails inNodeDetails)
{
    Logger.sysLog(LogValues.info, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] Inside sendHttpGetReq");
    String response = "";
    //response =  "{\"id\":\"584371732\",\"status_billing\":\"INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS\",\"status_sms\":\"NO_SMS\"}";
    String url = "";
    URL obj = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try
    {
        url = "http://"+inNodeConfig.getServerIp()+":"+inNodeConfig.getServerPort()+inNodeConfig.getServiceUri();
        url = url+urlParameters;
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.info, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] url = "+url);
        obj = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();     

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(inNodeConfig.getConTimeOut()));
        con.setReadTimeout(Integer.parseInt(inNodeConfig.getConTimeOut())+1000);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.info, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] HTTP Response Code : " + responseCode);
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.info, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] HTTP Response message : " + con.getResponseMessage());

        if(responseCode == 202 || responseCode == 200)
        {   
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer responseBf = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBf.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            Logger.sysLog(LogValues.info, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] Response received = "+responseBf.toString());

            response = responseBf.toString();
            responseBf = null;
            if(inNodeDetails.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase("digicel"))
            {
                if(response.startsWith("Received"))
                {
                    response = "ok";
                }
                else if(response.startsWith("{"))
                {
                    // {"id":"185688","status_billing":"INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS","status_sms":"FAILED"}
                    Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] Parsing json response.");
                    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
                    JsonResponse jsonResponse = gson.fromJson(response, JsonResponse.class);

                    if(jsonResponse.getStatus_billing().equalsIgnoreCase("ok") || jsonResponse.getStatus_billing().contains("SUCCESS")){
                        response="ok";
                    }
                    else if(jsonResponse.getStatus_billing().equalsIgnoreCase("INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"))
                    {
                        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] Response received for INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS.");
                        response = "low balance";
                    }
                    else if(jsonResponse.getStatus_billing().equalsIgnoreCase("FAILED"))
                    {
                        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] Failure Response received for some other reason.");
                        response = "nok";
                    }           
                    else
                    {
                        if(inNodeDetails.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("JAM")||inNodeDetails.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("HAI")){
                            response=jsonResponse.getStatus_billing();
                        }
                        else{
                            gson = null;
                            jsonResponse = null;
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(inNodeDetails.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("HAI") && response.contains("EXCEPTION"))
                    {
                        response = "ok";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] Unknown response.");
                    response = "nok";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(responseCode == 502 || responseCode == 500)
        {
            if(inNodeDetails.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("HAI") || inNodeDetails.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("JAM"))
            {
                response = "ok";
            }
            else
            {
                response = "nok";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            response = "nok";
            /*Map<String,List<String>> responseMap = con.getHeaderFields();
            for (Map.Entry entry : responseMap.entrySet()) {
                Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, Utility.class.getName(), "header key = "+entry.getKey() + " value = " + entry.getValue());
            }*/
        }

        return response;
    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException ex)
    {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, Utility.class.getName(), "Read Timeout occurs for msisdn = "+msisdn);
        return "ReadTimeout";
    }
    catch(ConnectTimeoutException ex1)
    {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, Utility.class.getName(), "ConnectTimeoutException occurs for msisdn = "+msisdn);
        return "ConnectionTimeout";
    }
    catch(ConnectException ex2)
    {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, Utility.class.getName(), "ConnectException occurs for msisdn = "+msisdn);
        return "ConnectionTimeout";
    }
    catch(JsonSyntaxException ex3){
        response=null;
        return response;
    }
    catch(MalformedJsonException ex4){
        response=null;
        return response;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.error, this.getClass().getName(),"["+msisdn+"] Internal Error occured"+coreException.GetStack(e));
        return response;
    }
    finally
    {
        response = null;
        url = null;
        obj = null;
        con.disconnect();
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, this.getClass().getName(),"Calling GC.");
        System.gc();
    }
    //return response;

}
```

However, the same code is running very fine in production environment with around 50 requests per second.

When i used the JVisualVM and Sampler, i got to know that this method "sendHttpGetReq" is taking a very long time and high CPU processing. But as from the code, i could find no specific reason where the code should block all the CPU.

Here is the Sampler screenshot:
[image]

Please suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: Check it with a profiler.

Comment: We can't debug this piece of code and tell you what part of it is causing your high CPU usage. You need to go and profile your code and have the profiler tell you where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @Kayaman I already used the jVisualVM and Sampler, and got to know that this particular code is taking large CPU time. Updated the question also.

Comment: @nos from Sampler only, i got to know that only this code is blocking.

Comment: Which part of that code? You have dozens of lines of code there, and visualvm is more than capable of telling you a more specific hotspot.

Comment: That is what the Sampler is telling me. From the whole application running which contains hundreds of files and methods, this is the method which is blocking.

Comment: Make up your mind. Blocking, or taking 100% CPU? It isn't the same thing.

Comment: @EJP It is not the same thing. My problem is that it is taking high CPU usage. Please look into the attached screenshot of sampler.

Comment: @DownVoters...Pls explain the reason for Down voting!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its System.gc() method which is being called in finally may cause the problem.
Suggest you to comment System.gc() and try it out.

Comment: You are right. Commenting out the System.gc() make the things fast. Thanks for your help. You saved my day. BTW but why is it working fine in production environment?

Comment: @KayV The production environment may have the `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` flag on for one. Really though, you should learn to use VisualVM better. It would've shown you directly that `System.gc()` is responsible (and don't argue that it doesn't, I've been using it for way long enough to know how it works). Also, you shouldn't be calling `System.gc()` anyway, and the code is not that great otherwise either. You could use a better library than going with `HttpURLConnection` directly.

Comment: @Kayaman Please look at the screenshot. VisualVM Sampler is showing nothing about the System.gc(). And the code is the legacy code written previously.